# Power coming out of breaker, no power to circuit

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit-breaker, light, smoke-detectors

I have a circuit that powers all smoke alarms, two hall lights, two outlets and a ceiling fan. This was working fine then stopped with no explication. I checked the breaker box and there is 120 out of every single pull breaker. I have checked for a hot wire in every smoke alarm and all hallway switches, ceiling fan, the two lights and the outlets. Not one has a hot wire. Attic has blown insulation so tracing wires is almost impossible. I did try with no hot wires over any of the smoke alarms but couldn’t find where the wire front the breaker to the first outlet/light/light switch is at. Super confused and annoyed. Any ideas?

Comment: You have a bad connection or a broken/chewed wire somewhere between the break and devices.  Both the black and white(live and neutral) wires must make a complete circuit.  Outlets using the push in connections are known trouble points.  Turn off the breaker and start checking the outlets, lights and alarms by pulling them out of the boxes.  Do not remove any wires before taking pictures.

Comment: Suggest you start exploring closest to the panel and work your way out.

Comment: You don't mention it, so just to be sure: did a GFCI outlet on the circuit trip? Ed: you say you checked outlets, so if you actually pulled them this probably isn't relevant. But if you just plugged something in to check, rule out a GFCI trip.

Comment: GFCI trip, bad connection, or given the apparent "poorly labeled breakers" since you mention "power from all" rather than knowing which breaker it is, the old "tripped breaker lives in a sub-panel you have't looked at" pretty much covers the bases.

Comment: I'm no code expert, but having lights, outlets & ceiling fans on the same circuit as the smoke detectors _sounds_ like a code violation. At a minimum, it seems like a Bad Idea™ for precisely _this_ reason.  There may be a back stab at a receptacle that's finally given up and now you've lost fire protection until you hunt it down. You might consider adding a circuit dedicated to the smoke detectors.